# Why does API Gateway's Method Request not block this test input?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I have an API Gateway with OPTIONS and POST methods, where the POST method has the following Method Request Model (with a content type of "application/json"):

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Basic User Request Schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "email" : { "type" : "string" },
    "id" : { "type" : "string" },
    "age" : { "type" : "string" },
    "count" : { "type" : "string" },
    "recaptcha" : { "type" : "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "email", "id", "age", "count", "recaptcha" ]
}
```

I then ran the "Test" for the POST method with the following request body (all other fields blank):

```
{
  "id": "Confused"
}
```

However, the test allows this input to make it all the way to the backend lambda, despite missing multiple required fields. **Why is this input not rejected by the Method Request?**

Here is the logs output:

```
Execution log for request HIDING_THIS_INFO
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: HIDING_THIS_INFO
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: HIDING_THIS_INFO
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: {
  "id": "Confused"
}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.HIDING_THIS_INFO/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:HIDING_THIS_INFO:function:HIDING_THIS_INFO/invocations
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request headers: {X-Amz-Date=20210324T174028Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=HIDING_THIS_INFO, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_HIDING_THIS_INFO, Host=lambda.HIDING_THIS_INFO.amazonaws.com, X-Amz-Content-Sha256=HIDING_THIS_INFO, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=HIDING_THIS_INFO, x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=HIDING_THIS_INFO, Authorization=*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************c2e0e4, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:HIDING_THIS_INFO/test-invoke-stage/POST/HIDING_THIS_INFO, X-Amz-Invocation-Type=Event, X-Amz-Security-Token=HIDING_THIS_INFO [TRUNCATED]
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
  "id": "Confused"
}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://lambda.HIDING_THIS_INFO.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:HIDING_THIS_INFO:function:HIDING_THIS_INFO/invocations
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Received response. Status: 202, Integration latency: 28 ms
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Wed, 24 Mar 2021 17:40:28 GMT, Content-Length=0, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=HIDING_THIS_INFO, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=HIDING_THIS_INFO;sampled=0}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: 
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method response body after transformations: 
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=HIDING_THIS_INFO;Sampled=0, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json}
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Successfully completed execution
Wed Mar 24 17:40:28 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status:
```

I actually get this 202 response code no matter what I send (i.e. for valid request body too).

FYI the backend lambda is being called asynchronously, and I have CORS enabled. **I have deployed the API.**

### Update

I modified the Request Model to make all properties integers and eliminate the required aspect, i.e.

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Basic User Request Schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "email" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "age" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "count" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "recaptcha" : { "type" : "integer" }
  }
}
```

I then redeployed the API. And even then, entering the same Test input did not fail (same Logs output as above)!

```
{
  "id": "Confused"
}
```

**I think I have to conclude there's a bug with API Gateway's console Test?!?** It seems to completely ignore the Method Request...

One final note: I also tried the following Test input, removing the double-quotes surrounding `id`:

```
{
  id: "Confused"
}
```

At least this did something different:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unexpected character (\'i\' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{\n    id: \"Confused\"\n}\"; line: 2, column: 6]"}
```

But again, this went all the way to the lambda; the Method Request did seemingly nothing.

For reference, [here are the specs for the Request Model language](https://json-schema.org/) (i.e. JSON Schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one thing to *define* a model for a certain request; it's another to have API Gateway *validate* that the request is consistent with the model you defined.

I think what you are looking for is the **Request Validator** setting for your method:
[image]

Comment: *facepalm* Yes, that was indeed the answer.